# Add new line in mini page - right col

Tags: line-breaking, minipage

I am interested to add new line after each company.
I try to achieve it by `\ \` or `\newline` but the text get right indented. Shown using colored rectangle.

Also, I'd like to have date in same line as company and not move to next line. Shown in elliptical in the image below.

One way to achieve this is have date with designation/post.

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt
 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry} % 

\usepackage{fontawesome}
 \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% must be the last package
 
 % ************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
 \renewcommand{\section}[1]{\noindent{\sectionfont#1}}
 \makeatletter
 \def\opening{\def\@opening{}%
    \begingroup
    \print@name%
    \endgroup}
 \makeatother
 % ************************************************** 
 
\begin{document} 
    
    \name{\bfseries First Last\\[12pt]} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% remove top margin.  reduce gap
    
     \address{ Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999 }
     \address{ mail[at]gmail[dot]com  \\ +91-70000-00000  \href{https://github.com/}{ \faGithub} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{ \faLinkedin} } 
    
    \begin{resume}
%%     \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
       \end{resume} % produce the header of the CV: name, address, etc
     
    \parindent0mm% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}

    \hfill % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \parindent3mm% <<<<<<<<<<< indent inside the minipage
        \section{Experience}  % next line must be blank!! 
        
      %%   \begin{itemize}
         
  {\bf Get more company}         \hfill Nov 2021 - \\
        {\it Senior Data Analyst } \\

{ \bf  Herbert University Medical Center} \hfill Oct'17 - Oct'21\\ 
{\it Staff associate } \\
{  \bf  Mason Washington University} Feb'15 - Oct'17 \\
       {\it Research Associate} \\
{ \bf    Software Tele solution Services} \hfill Nov'21 - July'13 \\
       {\it Software Engineer}
%%         \end {itemize} 
    \end{minipage}% 


\end{document}
```

How do I do this?
[image: right col edits]

Comment: The easy solution is to use `\hfill` to move text to the right margin.  Or use `\hfill\makebox[2cm][l]{...}` to align the left sides.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You can use a `tabular` environment within the `minipage` to make it easier to accommodate  your data.

(2) In order for the lines to fit half the width of the text, the font size must be smaller.

(3) To add vertical space between positions, use `\\[<space>]`.

(4) Avoid using `\bf` and `\it`. They are deprecated commands. Use `\bfseries` and `\itshape` instead.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry} % 

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% must be the last package

% ************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\noindent{\sectionfont#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\opening{\def\@opening{}%
    \begingroup
    \print@name%
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
% ************************************************** 

\begin{document} 
    
    \name{\bfseries First Last\\[12pt]} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% remove top margin.  reduce gap
    
    \address{ Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999 }
    \address{ mail[at]gmail[dot]com  \\ +91-70000-00000  \href{https://github.com/}{ \faGithub} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{ \faLinkedin} } 
    
    \begin{resume}
        %%     \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \end{resume} % produce the header of the CV: name, address, etc
    
    \parindent0mm% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}
    
    \hfill % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
        \section{Experience}  % next line must be blank!! 
        \footnotesize % added <<<<<<<<<<    
        
        \begin{tabular}{ll@{}}      
            {\bfseries Get more company}         & Nov 2021-- \\
            {\itshape Senior Data Analyst } & \\[1ex] % add vertical space      
            {\bfseries  Herbert University Medical Center} &  Oct'17--Oct'21\\ 
            {\itshape Staff associate } & \\[1ex]
            {\bfseries  Mason Washington University} &Feb'15--Oct'17 \\
            {\itshape Research Associate} &\\[1ex]
            {\bfseries    Software Tele solution Services} & Nov'21--July'13 \\
            {\itshape Software Engineer}    &
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{minipage}%     
\end{document}
```